# What does it mean "The logistics of the day and time"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Yesterday I attended an interview. They asked me to write a letter inquiry about lost luggage to airport manager. Three key points should include to build a letter. One of the key point is:

> "The logistics of the day and time when you can collect your luggage".

What does it mean? Why here logistics word were used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What they are asking is when and where they can deliver your luggage to you when they find it.  Will you be at home?  If you are staying at a hotel, do they give it to the concierge?

I am assuming they are using the BrE meaning of "*collect*" (to receive).
The AmE meaning would be that you go to the airport.